# Why does the use of "Debug.Print" lead to "Overflow" error?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I create a function to sum all the cells within a range as following

```
Function SumTest(rg As Range) As Double
  Debug.Print "SumTest..." 

  Dim s As Double
  s = 0 ' ------> Show runtime error "Overflow" at this line
  Dim i As Range
  For Each i In rg.Cells
      s = s + i.Value2
  Next i

  SumTest = s
End Function
```

When I run the function at the immediate window it complains runtime error  "Overflow", and it's very weird that the error message disappears after commenting the "Debug.Print" line. Does the function `Dbbug.Print` relate to double variable initialization? And why does the overflow happen here (I just assign the zero to a variable with `Double` data type)?

---

More information added:

I test the function at the immediate window as `?Sumtest(Range("A1:C1"))` (The range `A1:C1` is filled with trivial test data `1 2 3`). And the version of Excel is Office365 on Mac.

---

To simplify the test, I use another shorter program like this:

```
Function SumTest2() As Double

  Dim s As Double

  Debug.Print "SumTest2"
  s = 0  ' ---> Still "Overflow" here
  SumTest2 = s
End Function
```

---

After having testing a few programs I am considering this maybe a bug for Excel 2016 on Mac. It seems once you using `Debug.print` then you cannot assign value (0 or other value) to a variable with `Double` data type (Integer, String or other data types are ok..) any more. Following is another typical test program:

```
Sub DoubleTest2()
  Dim a As Double

  a = 0
  Debug.Print a  ' when this line appears, next assignment to variable `b` will complain `overflow` error message.

  Dim b As Double
  b = 100# ' *overflow error message*
  Debug.Print b
End Sub
```

Comment: How did you execute the function? In Excel or VBA (in a sub or function)? How many cells did you include? Just some more info, please.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thanks for reply! More information has bee added.

Comment: I have tested the function on windows 7 32 bit and office 2016 and it works without that overflow error

Comment: I've tested it on 2003, it works but is slow. I would use this   SumTest = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rg)

Comment: Really weird! If I execute the function in Excel `=SumTest2()` everything goes well. It only happens when using immediate window to run function..

Comment: In `SumTest2` I have tested too and no problem for me .. May be this because of your office version

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on a MacBook Pro 2.7 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5; Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015 running Excel for mac 16.59 (2022)

I commented out a couple of my `debug.print` statements, and noticed that some assigments did work even after a `debug.print` statement... The thing that "cured" the problem was an assigment `txt= space(20)`

playing around a bit, it appears that simply putting `space 0` after the last `debug.print` statement avoids the overflow error.... the mind boggles

I adapted your example

```
Function SumTest() As Double
1   Debug.Print "SumTest...":          ' s=s+... overflows
'2   Debug.Print "SumTest...": Space 0  '<<<< s=s+... works

    Dim s As Double
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        s = s + CDbl(i)
    Next i
    
3   Debug.Print s: Space 0
    SumTest = s
End Function
```

Note 1: as is, this code gives an overflow error at `s=s+cdbl(i)`, for no discernible reason
Note 2: uncommenting line 2, "repairs" the code, again no clear reason, its a serendipitous hack
Note 3: Commenting out the `Space 0` on line3 gives the overflow error again.
Note 4: calling the function from a cell in the spreadsheet (`=SumTest()`) does indeed not raise the error. it only happens when excecuting the code from within the VBE; either by pressing run, or entering it in `SumTest` in the immediate window

My guess is that debug.print requests memory for strings, but leaves a bit 'dangling', something that is corrected if when we reserve some more memory for strings with the `space` function. just conjecture though...

Answer (score -1):

Source: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/overflow-error-6) : An overflow results when you try to make an assignment that exceeds the limitations of the target of the assignment. This error has the following causes and solutions:

- The result of an assignment, calculation, or data type conversion is too large to be represented within the range of values allowed for that type of variable.

  - Assign the value to a variable of a type that can hold a larger range of values.
- An assignment to a property exceeds the maximum value the property can accept.

  - Make sure your assignment fits the range for the property to which it is made.

---

**Solution**:

Modify your code as below and you won't see the error again.

```
Function SumTest(rg As Range) As Double
  Debug.Print "SumTest..." 

  Dim s As Double
  Dim i As Range
  For Each i In rg.Cells
      s = s + CDbl(i.Value2)
  Next i

  SumTest = s
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But I don't think here the `CDbl` is the solution. It's just assignment without any calculation process, let alone the value to be assigned is 0 which fits `Double` data type size limit.